# Count rows over of multiple columns in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am new to learning R and have data table like below

```
    obj= c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A')
    x=c('Poor','Good','Good','Good','Poor','Poor','Poor','Good','Poor')
    y=c('High','Low','Low','Low','Low','Low','Low','Low','High')
    df = data.table(obj,x,y)


 df
obj    x    y
1:   A Poor High
2:   A Good  Low
3:   A Good  Low
4:   A Good  Low
5:   A Poor  Low
6:   A Poor  Low
7:   A Poor  Low
8:   A Good  Low
9:   A Poor High
```

I want to count number of row with good, bad from x columns also High, low from y column for a row in obj column.

I was able to do it for column x with below code.

```
dcast(df, obj ~ x, value.var=c("x"), fun.aggregate = length)
```

which gives me

```
 obj Good Poor
1:   A    4    5
```

However what I am trying to get is for both x and y columns like below.

```
obj Good Poor   High    Low
A   4    5       2       7
```

Comment: Do you want a `data.table` solution or do you accept any package/base R?

Comment: You probably will be better of with `melt`, e.g. `melt(df, 1)[, .N, by = .(obj, value)]` though you could also do `df[, as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, table))), by = obj]` but that probably will be less efficient.

Comment: As of now it would be good if I have any solution. but I do want to do it with data.table

Comment: Thanks @ David Arenburg. I did with next step ` x <-melt(df, 1)[, .N, by = .(obj, value)]` `
dcast(x, obj ~ value, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var='N') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @DavidArenburg's comment-answers, you can do...

```
df[, Reduce(`c`, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.list(table(x)))), by = obj]

#    obj Good Poor High Low
# 1:   A    4    5    2   7
```

Or ...

```
dcast(melt(df, "obj"), 
  obj ~ paste(variable, value, sep="."), 
  fun.aggregate = length)

#    obj x.Good x.Poor y.High y.Low
# 1:   A      4      5      2     7
```

Or...

```
melt(df, "obj")[, .N, keyby=.(obj, variable, value)]

#    obj variable value N
# 1:   A        x  Good 4
# 2:   A        x  Poor 5
# 3:   A        y  High 2
# 4:   A        y   Low 7
```

The last way is better for later analysis, since variable and value can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure to incur some wrath from the `data.table` folks here, but here's a `tidyverse` solution for anyone who's interested:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 mutate(value = 1,
        value_1 = 1) %>%
 spread(key = x, value = value) %>%
 spread(key = y, value = value_1) %>%
 select(-rowid) %>%
 mutate_at(vars(Good:Low), funs(if_else(is.na(.), 0, .))) %>%
 group_by(obj) %>%
 summarize_all(funs(sum))
```